# Attempting to connect to database via PDO, why cant I connect successfully?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am using XAMPP on a Windows machine. I have reviewed similar questions here regarding the topic, but none helped in resolving my problem. I have successfully connected via procedural PHP and OOP and now that I am trying to connect to the same database via PDO, I get an

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Below you will find the code, I have tried putting the dbname before the host, I have tried doing it without the charset, I have tried doing it as in the PHP manual and I have tried removing the h in $dbh, I have tried writing localhost instead of the IP address and I still get this error. By the way I do not have a password so that one is empty. Again when doing procedural and OOP it worked, why not the PDO way?

```
<?php

try {
    // Connect to DB
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8','root',' ');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Display Errors
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: You're sending space(s) as a password when you setup your connection. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add a password to the parameters all while MySQL is expecting one to be given, add the password you use to login to the database yourself to the parameters, and you should be able to connect.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host = {hostname} ; dbname = {dbname}", "username", "password");
```

There are spaces in your password parameter which could also be seen as a password if you don't have a password set, just have the ' & ' hug eachother and it could be fixed

Comment: Simplicity you are awesome! That's exactly what it was. I noticed after I read your answer that in my procedural and OOP version the quotes were hugging each other. I will be checking your answer soon. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Glad to be able to help @DanielCortes